# Command prompt output to Excel file in arranged format

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, command-line-arguments

We can display command prompt in .CSV file using > and >> but how to arrange these output in .CSV file.

Eg: When we run multiple commands each output should be stored in different columns.

Comment: show the example output and expected output, and also show your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your results with commas.  One way is to assign your results to variables then redirect them to the CSV file all at once.

```
set c1="command one"
set c2="command two"
echo %c1%,%c2% > myFile.csv
```

Comment: When I run this script, the 2 commands command one and command two are stored in file myFile.csv but I need the result of commands to be stored in file.

Comment: @VinodhGowda this [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/245679/store-output-of-windows-command-in-batch-file) has some ways to store the results of commands to variables.  All of this would be much easier in another shell program like powershell or bash etc..